# Auto-arrange child controls of a TToolWindow control

Tags: delphi, controls, toolbar, delphi-10.3-rio

I want to build a custom toolbar. I created a new class from `TToolWindow` - this will be the base, on which the other controls will be placed (mostly speed buttons). I also have the algorithm for arranging the controls (called `RearrangeControls`). Now I just have to see where should I fire that procedure. I did some research and I managed to rearrange the controls when they are dropped or removed from my toolbar. Removing controls seems to work fine. I catch the `CM_CONTROLLISTCHANGE` message and I call there the arranging method. But there are still some problems...

=> Inserting controls - not working as it should, if it is done at runtime. When I call `RearrangeControls` from the `CM_CONTROLCHANGE`, all controls are arranged ok, but not the newest added. And that is because, when I receive that message, the control that I just added is not yet scalled (I have a 134 dpi monitor), and later, when it is scalled, its position and size change.

=> I also don't know what to override to catch the child controls when they are changhing their size or position (design time/run time).

=> And where else should I call `RearrangeControls` to have a fully functional arranging alghorithm ?

LightControls.pas

```
unit LightControls;

interface

uses
  System.Classes, System.SysUtils,
  Winapi.Messages, Winapi.Windows, Winapi.CommCtrl,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.ToolWin;

type
  TPngToolBar = class(TToolWindow)
  private
    procedure CMControlChange(var Msg: TCMControlChange); message CM_CONTROLCHANGE;
    procedure CMControlListChange(var Msg: TCMControlListChange); message CM_CONTROLLISTCHANGE;

  protected
    procedure Resize; override;

  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor  Destroy; override;
    procedure RearrangeControls;
  end;

procedure Register;

implementation

procedure Register;
begin
 RegisterComponents('OwnMisc', [TPngToolBar]);
end;

constructor TPngToolBar.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
 inherited Create(AOwner);
 ControlStyle:= ControlStyle + [csAcceptsControls];
end;

destructor TPngToolBar.Destroy;
begin
 inherited;
end;

procedure TPngToolBar.Resize;
begin
 RearrangeControls;
end;

procedure TPngToolBar.CMControlChange(var Msg: TCMControlChange);
begin
 inherited;
 if Msg.Inserting then RearrangeControls;
end;

procedure TPngToolBar.CMControlListChange(var Msg: TCMControlListChange);
begin
 inherited;
 if not Msg.Inserting then RearrangeControls;
end;

procedure TPngToolBar.RearrangeControls;
var X, I: Integer;
begin
 X:= 0;
 for I:= 0 to ControlCount -1 do begin
  Controls[I].Left:= X;
  Controls[I].SetBounds(X, 0, Controls[I].Width, ClientHeight);
  Inc(X, Controls[I].Width);
 end;
end;

end.
```

MainUnit.pas

```
unit MainUnit;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.ToolWin, Vcl.ComCtrls,
  Vcl.Buttons, PngSpeedButton, LightControls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    BAddButton: TButton;
    PngToolBar1: TPngToolBar;
    PngSpeedButton4: TPngSpeedButton;
    procedure BAddButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    ToolBar: TPngToolBar;
    N: Integer;
    procedure SpeedClick(Sender: TObject);
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
 ToolBar:= TPngToolBar.Create(Self);
 ToolBar.Parent:= Self;
 ToolBar.SetBounds(50, 50, 300, 50);
 N:= 1;
end;

procedure TForm1.BAddButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
 with TPngSpeedButton.Create(ToolBar) do begin
  Caption:= IntToStr(N); Inc(N);
  OnClick:= SpeedClick;
  Parent:= ToolBar;
 end;
end;

procedure TForm1.SpeedClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
 Sender.Free;
end;

end.
```

Answer (score 2):

I can't believe how simple it was ! I just had to override the `AlignControls` method, and my controls are arranged whenever needed.

```
procedure AlignControls(AControl: TControl; var Rect: TRect); override;

procedure TPngToolBar.AlignControls(AControl: TControl; var Rect: TRect);
begin
 RearrangeControls;
// inherited;   - not needed, I do my own arrangement
end;
```